# How can I get... just a little bit higher?

Tags: genshin-impact

I often get collectibles like this.

[image]

They are just out of reach of a jump. So, is there a way to jump just a small bit higher (or by another mechanic to just get a little bit higher) to get those pieces?

Comment: Head to your nearest dispensary?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use many characters attributes and skills to acquire these.

There are mainly two options that can be accessed simply by progressing the game and thus are available for free:

- the [Wind Catcher](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Wind_Catcher) gadget can be used to place a wind current anywhere;
- if you have the **Traveler** as **Geo** (available as soon as you enter the Liyue region), their elemental skill can create a platform to climb;

Other options are available, but they all require access to limited characters that *as now* can only be acquired from the gacha wish system (either with paid or free  currency you get from rewards in the game):

- if you have **Venti**, his elemental skill also creates a wind current(but only after 1st Ascension);
- if you have **Albedo**, his elemental skill spawns elevator like platform;
- if you have **Keqing**, her elemental skill could be used as a short range teleport;
- if you have **Zhongli**, his elemental skill summons a pillar and you can jump on top of it;
- if you have **Kazuha**, his elemental skill includes a high jump;
- if you have **Xiao**, his elemental burst enables high jumps and dashing above the ground.

Also, characters height differs, sometimes it could be enough to switch to higher one. For example, **Kaeya** is one of the tallest characters available for free.

Comment: Also Kazuha's skill, Zhongli's pillar, or Xiao's burst, and for completeness, it's worth pointing out that sometimes you just need to switch to a taller character to reach higher.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks, that's nice addition! converted the answer into community wiki since you added half of it :)

Comment: Can Kequing teleport off the ground?

Comment: @pjc50 yes. You can hold the elemental skill button and aim where to place the stiletto.

Comment: I know im a little late to the party here, but for anyone wondering about this geoculus in particular, ive found if you use Kaeya, mash the jump button and do a plummet attack, itll register just enough pixels to collect it :)

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using the anemo traveler in your screenshot, these "just out of reach" puzzles in Liyue are usually designed with the geo traveler in mind because he/she can easily summon a boulder and climb atop to reach the item.

Try changing your traveler to Geo at the nearest statue and give it another shot.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Changing the traveler to Geo has already been mentioned as a method

Comment: Haha yeah, but I thought I'd add some more context on why these puzzles are usually Liyue exclusive